# Plotting two y axes in a bar plot for list of lists

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two lists of lists as follows.

```
list1=[[0,2],[1,4],[2,5]]
list2=[[0,3.5],[1,9],[2,0.2]]
```

I want to have a bar plot of both the lists side by side with two y axes. The X-axis values are same for both (1st elements of the lists inside).

I have managed to have them on the same plot but with only one y axis with the following code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
x1,y1 = zip(*list1)
x2,y2 = zip(*list2)
plt.figure()
plt.bar(np.array(x1)-0.15, y1, width = 0.3)
plt.bar(np.array(x2)+0.15, y2, width = 0.3)

plt.xticks(range(min(x1+x2), max(x1+x2)+1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a twin axis. This can be done using `twinx()`. Complete answer is below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

list1=[[0,2],[1,4],[2,5]]
list2=[[0,3.5],[1,9],[2,0.2]]

x1,y1 = zip(*list1)
x2,y2 = zip(*list2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(np.array(x1)-0.15, y1, width = 0.3, color='blue')
ax.set_ylabel('List 1', fontsize=16)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.bar(np.array(x2)+0.15, y2, width = 0.3, color='red')
ax2.set_ylabel('List 2', fontsize=16)

plt.xticks(range(min(x1+x2), max(x1+x2)+1))
plt.show()
```

[image]